# Let $f(x)=(x-a)g(x)$. Calculate $f '(a)= g(a)$.

Tags: functions

Assuming that $g$ is continuos. What is $f(a)$ in this case? Can you give an explanation for this proof? How can it be possible to ask about a function of another variable of an existing function? Can you give other examples? This made me question my understanding of functions.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Not true. $f(x)=(x-a)g(x)$ gives $f(a)=0$ so $f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)/(x-a)=\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=g(a)$ assuming only continuity.

Comment: Write the *definition* of the derivative $f'(a)$ of $f$ at $a$ in terms of a limit. And for that, first look at what the difference quotient $\frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h}$ is.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff You are right. I didn't take enough time to think.

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff why is $f(a) = 0$?

Comment: @user3063381 we've defined $f(x) = (x - a)g(x)$.  Even if we don't know what number $a$ is and what function $g$ is, we still know that
$$
f(a) = (a - a)g(a) = 0 \cdot g(a) = 0
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have  $f(a) = 0,$ and from the definition of the derivative $$f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} = \lim_{x \to a} g(x) = g(a)  .$$ in the last step the continuity of $g$ at $x = a$ is used.

Comment: why is $f(a) = 0$?

Comment: @user3063381 $f(a)=(a-a)g(a)=0 \cdot g(a)$.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be that if $f(a)=0$, then forming the difference quotient makes $$\frac{f(a+\Delta a)-f(a)}{\Delta a}=\frac{(((a+\Delta a)-a)g(x))-0}{\Delta a}=\frac{\Delta a \ g(x)}{\Delta a}=g(x).$$
(Hello to anybody running across this from OCW.)